# how to publish c# window application installer

Tags: c#, mysql, installshield

[image]

I'm trying to publish C# Windows application. I tried to install shield and visual studio installer but it does not work properly.

This setup can install only on those laptops or PC in which visual studio is installed. can anyone help me what are prerequisites are required and how can publish installer setup.exe

app.config

connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_string"].ConnectionString);

but it occurs error
[failed to update database because the database is read-only visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhPp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the prerequisites. The .net version on which you have created the application will be required along with other prerequisites. It's not visual studio that is required to run the executable, but just the .net framework.

Comment: its .net 4.5.2 . that i also installed in pc where i try t run setup which i had published

Comment: Can you provide more details, like the error, screen shot or some additional info that could help in understanding the problem? Right now it's too generic.

Comment: I have a local DB that I have in an application. When I install it on another machine I get the error

Unable to update database.. .mdf is read only.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem about how to get the setup file to work in any other device although it takes some time for me to understand the process but finally i have found that it's really simple.

1) you have to change the **connection string** to something like that :

```
string connectionStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

2) you can use **Advanced Installer** to generate the setup file, the process is simple, you can watch any short tutorial about how to get the setup file in Advanced Installer.

3) Finally, You have to install 3 programs as **Prerequisites** in client pc :

- .Net Framework (I think started from version 4.5)
- Sql Server Express
- SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio)

Comment: every thing works with me without any problem after follow this process .. good luck !

Comment: <add name="connection_string" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\silver.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_string"].ConnectionString);

Comment: error -failed to update database because the database is read-only visual studio

Comment: you need to make the database files full control while generating the setup file in Advanced Installer.

Comment: how to? and where apply this full control

Comment: do you use advanced installer to generate setup file ? if so, in files and folders .. you should find the 2 database files if not, add them then select them and click properties then click permission finally select new and check full control and press ok.

Comment: i tried advance installer and install shield both and also i give full access